# How to get copied clipboard text from Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium python script that clicks a button and once the button is clicked some text is copied. I couldn't get the text through the code directly, but when clicking the button I verified manually that it does copy to the clipboard. So I have to now leverage the clipboard and get the text.

**Here is my script**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# have to copy n paste the "user data" folder to a unique one otherwise they fight over each other
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Selenium Data')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 2')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) # ignore dumb USB errors
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=Service(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH))

driver.get("url")

username_copy = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-tabs"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
username_copy.click()
```

So far I have tried the following, but nothing is returned.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="rc-tabs"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div').text
```

---

```
text = username_copy.click()
print(text)
```

Unfortunately, sending ctrl v command or any shortcut is not a solution because I want to pass this variable from python into a PowerShell script. Ideally I would like to figure out a way to accomplish this without the need to install additional python packages. All in all my goal is something along the lines of this:

```
username_copy = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-tabs"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div')

username = username_copy.click()
run_Powershell(ps_script, username)
```

**Appreciate any help in advance!**

Comment: Can you include the html element with the click function and the text to be copied.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? 
I ran
username_copy.get_attribute('innerHTML')

and got the below

'<div class="psds-icon psds-icon--size-xsmall" style="flex-shrink: 0;"><svg aria-label="copy icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21 7a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H8a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V7zM9 20h10V8H9v12z"></path><path d="M16.5 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5v13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12.5z"></path></svg></div>'

the username is just a randomly generated user name like "Un22784"